# IDA Array of structs hiding strings

Tags: ida, struct, array

I have just started teaching myself IDA and I have had some trouble with an array of structs.

I have found and defined a struct similar to this: (simplified)

```
struct {
char filename[50];
int field2;
int field3;
}
```

I then found an array of these.

So I defined the struct, and then the array.

Before I defined them, the filename showed as a comment wherever it was referenced in the code.

Now however, it only references the first element of the array and an offset.
So now looking through the code, I don't have comments with the file being referenced, which makes it hard to tell what file the code is working on.

Is there a way for me to keep the array of structs and the comments, or do I need to undefine the array & struct to get the comment with filename back?

EDIT:
I forgot to add, the filenames also no longer show up in the strings window after I created the array of structs

EDIT 2:
Here is my struct definition

```
000000 file_data_struct_t struc ; (sizeof=0x4F)
00000000 base_file_path  db 18 dup(?)            ; string(C)
00000012 unknown         db 44 dup(?)
0000003E loaded_data_ptr dd ?                    ; offset
00000042 ptr2            dd ?                    ; offset
00000046 file_length     db ?
00000047 unknown3        db ?
00000048 unknown4        db ?
00000049 unknown5        db ?
0000004A use_2nd_func    db 4 dup(?)
0000004E flag            db ?
0000004F file_data_struct_t end
```

This is for the game [Theme Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theme_Park_(video_game))

Comment: Can you paste your IDA struct definition?

Comment: I added my current structure definition, let me know if anything else would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press <kbd>*</kbd> and uncheck 'Create as array'. This will convert the array into separate structs, and you'll see the strings again.

Comment: I just tried that and the filename is still not present in the strings view or as a comment.
It does at least give it an individual label though, which I can find references to.